# STS reports error in bean config for java.sql.Date property

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I have a bean class with a property setter like this:

```
public void setDueDate(java.sql.Date dueDate)
```

I also have an instance of this bean configured in XML like this:

```
<property name="dueDate">
    <bean class="java.sql.Date"/>
</property>
```

STS marks that config with an error:
`No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class 'java.sql.Date'`

Well, that's true, `java.sql.Date` has no no-arg constructor. But this app works fine so obviously Spring is smart enough to create a `Date` instance without a constructor. Question is, why is the STS editor/builder complaining, and is it possible to convince it that this is not an error or warning?

Comment: If the code works, then this looks like a bug in STS. You can write a JIRA(https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS) or post in the Spring forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, I can only see 3 situations where the code "would work", in the order of their likeliness to happen:

1. the parent bean where the property is injected is defined with `scope="prototype"` or `lazy-init="true"` and is not accessed at all
2. the runtime classpath contains an implementation of `java.sql.Date`shadowing the original
3. that particular context xml is not used in the application

Otherwise, Spring should issue a nice:

```
Could not instantiate bean class [java.sql.Date]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.sql.Date.<init>()
```

Comment: You got it, the beans with this problem are all scoped as `prototype` and in my testing thus far they are not actually accessed (still have some investigating to do as this app is called by some batch scripts with different params and input data).

Comment: I'm not used to having or seeing a lot of `prototype` beans, so I didn't even think to look for that. Ah, the perils of jumping into an existing application.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance; have fun with that legacy code :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the code works, but STS reports an wrong error, please file a bug against STS at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS (as mentioned above).

In the meantime you can workaround this issue by disabling the validation via the Spring preferences for the project. Just go to preferences of the project -> Spring, then the "Project Validators" tab, and deactivate the validation that is responsible for the wrong error report.